# How to create payable contract solidity

Tags: contract-development, payable

```
contract Test {
    constructor() public payable {

    }
}
contract MyContract {
    constructor() public payable {
        Test test = new Test();
    }
}
```

How do I pay the Test contract's constructor?

Comment: You should describe how you are deploying it!

Comment: from the contract

Comment: You're deploying the contract from itself? Very nice! Please explain exactly what off-chain tool you are using (e.g., web3.js, web3.py, Remix IDE, etc). And please share the relevant code along with this explanation!

Comment: Im using web3.js I know how to pay the first constructor but not the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass exactly what you've received:

```
Test test = (new Test).value(msg.value)();
```

If you want to pass, for example, half of what you've received:

```
Test test = (new Test).value(msg.value / 2)();
```

If you want to pass, for example, a constant value of 100 wei:

```
Test test = (new Test).value(100)();
```

Of course, you'll need `msg.value >= 100` in order for that one to work.